# What is the origin of the Esperanto green star ("Verda Stelo")?

Tags: culture, history

What is the origin of the Esperanto green star symbol (**Verda Stelo**)?

[image: Green star (verda stelo)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Verda Stelo was created by Zamenhof in 1892 as a symbol for Esperantists.

When asked about this, he said,

> "It seems to me, that my attention was drawn to the color green by Mr. [R. H.] Geoghegan and from that time I began to publish all of my works with green covers . . . Looking at one of my pamphlets that I had entirely by chance printed with a green cover, he pointed out that this was the color of his homeland, Ireland; at that time it came to me, that we could certainly look at that color as a symbol of HOPE. About the five-pointed star, it seems to me, that at first Mr. de Beaufront had it imprinted on his grammar [of Esperanto]. I liked that and I adopted it as a symbol. Afterward by association of ideas, the star appeared with a green color."

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_symbols)

Note that this quote wasn't sourced, but I've seen this explanation often enough that it seems to be quite likely.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quote from a reputable source.

> 6.7. Does Esperanto have a logo or symbol?
>
> Yes, there are several. The green star is the oldest and most widely
> used: it appears on the Esperanto flag, among other places. The colour
> green stands for hope, and the five-pointed star represents the five
> continents.
>
> http://www.ikso.net/en/en/broshuro/tradukoj/6.php